# C# 7.0 - Achieve multiple inheritance with default implementation

Tags: c#, interface, abstract-class, multiple-inheritance

The question is: how to provide both multiple inheritance (not allowed by C#) and default methods implementation (not allowed by interface in C# < 8.0)?

The general scenario is when I have a first abstraction layer, then a second abstraction layer generating two distinct families/categories, finally a concrete implementation of something that belongs to both the above families/categories.

The example code I wrote is the following (but please do not focus too much on the implementation details, just consider this as a descriptive scenario):

```
public abstract class Message
{
    protected Guid _id;
    protected string _body;
    protected Message(string body)
    {
        _body = body;
    }
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return _id + "|" + _body;
    }
}
public abstract class ReceivableMessage : Message
{
    private string _receivedFrom;
    public ReceivableMessage(string body, string receivedFrom)
    : base(body)
    {
        _receivedFrom = receivedFrom;
    }
    public string GenerateReply()
    {
        //do some generation
        return "";
    }
}
public abstract class SendableMessage : Message
{
    private string _sendTo;
    public SendableMessage(string body, string sendTo)
    : base(body)
    {
        _sendTo = sendTo;
    }
    public bool CheckReply(ReceivableMessage reply)
    {
        //do some check
        return true;
    }
}
```

then I have several concrete implementations of both `ReceivableMessage` and `SendableMessage`; but now I want to add concrete classes `AckMessage` and `NackMessage`...they should extend both `ReceivableMessage` and `SendableMessage` (because both can be received and can be sent)...how can I achieve this?
As additional comments I have considered two possibilities but discarded them:

1. substitute 3 abstract classes with 3 interfaces. Not ok, because I would lose the common method implementations `ToString`, `GenerateReply` and `CheckReply` and I should repeat them in all the concrete classes, as well as the common fields `_id`, `_body`, `_receivedFrom` and `_sendTo` (even if technically this could be avoided replacing them with properties).
2. provide concrete implementations for `AckReceivableMessage` and `NackReceivableMessage` (inheriting from `ReceivableMessage`), as well as `AckSendableMessage` and `NackSendableMessage` (inheriting from `SendableMessage`). Not ok, this seems to me code duplication.

Comment: There's no multiple inheritance in C#, even in 8. DIMs don't provide multiple inheritance, nor are they substitutes for abstract classes

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I know there is no multiple inheritance in version 8.0 *(not allowed by C#)* (I am not specifying any version, hence not allowed for all versions). Regarding DIMs achronim, I am very sorry but I don't know what you are referring to.

Comment: Why do you consider inheritance in the first place? Inheritance isn't a code-reuse mechanism. You have a bunch of messages. Do you want to treat some of them the same way? One or more interfaces would be a good idea. Extension methods could provide extra functionality for each interface.

Comment: The feature is Default Interface Member (hence DIM), not default method implementation

Comment: `I know there is no multiple inheritance in version 8.0` you still considered using default interface members as a way to implement multiple inheritance. That's now that it's for. In this way it would be a way to implement traits, accessible only through the interface itself. For consumers, this would be similar to using extension methods on the interfaces

Comment: are you referring to this: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/default-implementations-in-interfaces/ , right? I will go in deeper reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created multiple inheritance by using dynamic dispatch. It's an overly complicated way to accomplish the properties of a mass customization system. What you fundamentally want is the ability to integrate processing from multiple modules. Manufacturing architecture allows a container to infinitely grow -- these terms are from business -- in two ways:

- Vertically:  extending the process (instead of subclassing to do it)
- Horizontally:  adding new processes (instead of subclassing or inheriting to do it)

Multiple inheritance's other problem is that it introduces ambiguity. It is unclear which method should be invoked when both classes are inherited.

```
    class A
    {
        public void One() { ... }
    }
    class B
    {
        public void One() { ... }
    }
```

Manufacturing architecture such as mass customization, however, models processes as whole classes not just methods, and so the above problem is prevented by namespaces.

```
namespace A
{
    class OneProduct { ... }
    class One : Producer<OneProduct>, IProcess { ... }
}

namespace B
{
    class OneProduct { ... }
    class One : Producer<OneProduct>, IProcess { ... }
}

// example of a hardcoded process
namespace IntegratingProcess
{
    class MyProduct { ... }
    class MyProcess : Producer<OneProduct>, IProcess 
    {
        private A.One Machine1 { get; set; }
        private B.One Machine2 { get; set; }
        void D() { // allocate memory for all machines and product DTO }
        void O() { // binds Machine1 and Machine2 to MyProduct reference properties }
        void M()
        {
            Machine1.M();
            Machine2.M();
        }
    }

}
```

Mass customization allows you to **dynamically** integrate processing and change firing order. This is of course an alternative to the hardcoded form above, where the production process and its firing order is built at compile-time. My R article covers mass customization, but I don't give away the source code for it.

I am the developer of POWER, a manufacturing architecture and the rules to effectively wield it. My articles instruct programmers on how to correctly model collaborative work with source code.

http://www.powersemantics.com/power.html